# How can I get the index of a table with pagination (NG-ZORRO, Angular)?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I'm truggling getting the index of a row into a table with pagination, for the first page there's no problem, the problem is when I go to the second page, the first row shows index "0" and it should be 10 as the first page has 10 rows.

**this is what I got in my template file:**

```
<nz-table #basicTable [nzData]="listOfData">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Número de Solicitud</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Identificación</th>
      <th>Fecha de solicitud</th>
      <th>FATCA</th>
      <th>PEP</th>
      <th nzRight>Detalle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of basicTable.data; index as i">
      <td>{{ data.idProcessFlow }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.firstSurname }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.identification }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.createdDate | date: "shortDate" }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.isFATCA }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.isPEP }}</td>
      <td nzRight>
        <a nzType="link" nzBlock (click)="ver(i)">Ver Detalle</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

**and this is what i got in my TS file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SolicitudesService } from '../../services/solicitudes.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-Solicitudes',
  templateUrl: './Solicitudes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Solicitudes.component.scss'],
})
export class SolicitudesComponent implements OnInit {
  listOfData = [];


  constructor(private solicitudes: SolicitudesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.solicitudes.getTodasSolicitudes().subscribe((data) => {
      this.listOfData = data['Data']

    });


}
ver(i:number){
console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to code in question above, we can use `#basicTable` to get page index and page size.

`basicTable.nzPageIndex` will give us a page number start with 1.

`basicTable.nzPageSize` default will be 10.

So, we can use `((basicTable.nzPageIndex - 1) * basicTable.nzPageSize) + i` to represent row index start with 0 at the first page, 10 for the second page and 30 for the third.

Hope this can help.